# Cant remove the default blue highlight on blackberry webworks app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Im currently working on a Blackberry webworks app and having problems removing the default blue highlight on links. I've following the guides on the blackberry site and added the:

```
<meta name="x-blackberry-defaultHoverEffect" content="false" />
```

and the css

```
a:hover{background-color:transparent}
```

I've tried all sorts of background css properties with no luck.

Neither of these are working.

Answer (score 2):

3 years later, so this probably won't help the asker, but just in case someone else comes across it, I found the magic hidden property to fix this:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. In my css I used:

```
/* Links */
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #353535;
    font-weight: bold
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

and then:

```
#my-content .txt a{
    color: #BF3232;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}   
#my-content .txt a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It worked for me.

Cheers.